# make $index value start form 1 instead of zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that produce its data using ng-repeat. So I use `{{$index}}` for a column to indicate numbers of item, but how to instead of displaying 0 at first, start from 1?

I just want to change the index value, not discarding the first item of my data set.

Comment: How about `{{$index + 1}}`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `{{$index || 1}}`

This means if `$index === 0` show `1` else show `$index`

Comment: With this op will have 2 columns with `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

ng-if = "$index != 0"

this will not create for the first element

Answer (score 0):

> **$index**

`$index` is the iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1).

It is used by angular internally to identify each element in array or object. You can change it, But if you are referring it anywhere, You can use `{{$index+1}}`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you used **ng-init** like:

`<ul ng-init="items=[100, 20, 50, 40]">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="index_ = $index+1">{{index_}}</li>
<ul>`